# How does XSL FO process javascript scripts?

Tags: javascript, xslt, xsl-fo

I have been trying for some time to figure out a way to use a javascript script within an XSL FO template to produce a PDF. After alot of digging I'm starting to realize it may not be possible however, since, as i understand, the order of operation for turning XML data into a rendered PDF form is

XML -> XSL(transformation) -> FO(formating gets applied) -> PDF rendering engine -> PDF

My question is, where does the javascript execution fit within this pipeline? It seems clear that the script is executed AFTER the xsl transformations have finished being performed, which is why alot of people run into complications with browser based XSL transformations, but if the javascript portion is executed after the xsl transformations, but before the FO formatting is applied, then technically should there not be a way to still have your javascript script perform some action like updating a parameter in the xsl fo document that would be incorporated by the FO phase and thus output to the PDF to be seen?

Comment: I think the answer to this depends on the tool you're using, but I can't imagine why anybody would build JavaScript support into a processing engine like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing a browser with a formatting engine. A formatting engine takes input and makes print output (not interactive output). You can either put code in Java or .NET (depending on your XSLT engine) to modify XSL FO before it reaches the formatting engine ... or (if your FO engine supports it) embed Javascript into the final output (PDF only obviously) for modifying what happens when viewing it. No XSL FO engine (as far as I know) would support Javascript in the process pipeline -- that is a server process where Javascript is not (normally) executed (as it is not in your browser).